# graph API large post thumbnail

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working with the graph api and I ran into a problem: I get all the feeds from my page using: `https://graph.facebook.com/page_ID/posts` and then I display them in a nice way that requires larger thumbnails than the really small ones returned in `data[i].picture` .

I know it's possible for profile pictures... I've been reading the doc quite a bit and looking around and now I've got no clues... Have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing FQL query to get the posts like so:

```
SELECT post_id, message, permalink, attachment, actor_id, created_time FROM stream WHERE source_id = PAGE_ID AND message != ""
```

If that still brings the same image size you can use this hack:

**Disclaimer**: 
This is not a good method as Facebook may change the image path anytime.

That been said, for every image with this file name format:
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_s.jpg`

You can change the letter "s" just before the ".jpg" to "n" and get a bigger version like so:
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_n.jpg`

Changing it to "q" will give you an image with a width of no more then 180 pixels
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_q.jpg`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll use that unsafe solution it works well ftm... However, Do you know why Facebook does give access through the API to these other sizes? It does for the profile for eg I don't see why not for the posts too...

Comment: using the FQL you get `aid` and `pid` which is the album id and picture id - I think you can query another table to get the path of all the sizes of the photo, but I haven't tried that before.